# How can I edit/rename keys during json.load in python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a json file ( ~3Gb ) that I need to load into mongodb. Quite a few of the json keys contain a . (dot), which causes the load into mongodb to fail. I want to the load the json file, and edit the key names in the process, say replace the dot with an empty space. Using the following python code

```
import json

def RemoveDotKey(dataPart):
    for key in dataPart.iterkeys():
        new_key = key.replace(".","")
        if new_key != key:
            newDataPart = deepcopy(dataPart)
            newDataPart[new_key] = newDataPart[key]
            del newDataPart[key]
            return newDataPart
    return dataPart

new_json = json.loads(data, object_hook=RemoveDotKey)
```

The object_hook called RemoveDotKey should iterate over all the keys, it a key contains a dot, create a copy, replace the dot with a space, and return the copy. Created a copy of dataPart, since not sure if I can iterate over dataPart's keys and insert/delete key value pairs at the same time.

There seems to be an error here, all the json keys with a dot in them are not getting edited. I am not very sure how json.load works. Also am new to python ( been using it for less than a week )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
import json

def remove_dot_key(obj):
    for key in obj.keys():
        new_key = key.replace(".","")
        if new_key != key:
            obj[new_key] = obj[key]
            del obj[key]
    return obj

new_json = json.loads(data, object_hook=remove_dot_key)
```

You were returning a dictionary inside your loop, so you'd only modify one key.  And you don't need to make a copy of the values, just rename the keys.

Comment: Isn't that code going to run into problems updating the dictionary while iterating over it? I would have thought you need to make a list of keys instead of using `iterkeys()`

Comment: Not creating deep copies of obj speeds up the json load process significantly, and replacing the iterkeys() with keys() is the key! Thank you Ned, Duncan.