# Cleaning/parsing JSON with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

Can anyone help to clean below JSON

```
"1-Transaction Transfer Info Segment-F2":{
    "Selling Store Number":"01818",
    "Transaction Date":"2014-09-08",
    "Transaction Time":"05:45:49",
    "Transaction Service Type":"I",
    "IP Time Id":"118180546186"
}
```

I want  to clean this json as below

```
    1-Transaction Transfer Info Segment-F2 =>1_Transaction_Transfer_Info_Segment_F2
    Selling Store Number => Selling_Store_Number,
Transaction Service Type => Transaction_Servic_Type,
IP Time Id => IP_Time_Id
```

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188889/how-can-i-edit-rename-keys-during-json-load-in-python

Comment: i have solved it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not valid JSON - surround the entire thing with braces {}

For future reference, there are many online JSON validators/viewers which will quickly tell you whether or not you're working with valid JSON.

Just to name a few:

- http://jsoneditoronline.org
- http://jsonlint.com/