# Python: Encode JSON Keys for MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, encoding

I'm searching for a method to escape all characters in **all** JSON-Keys in a JSON string that are not accepted by MongoDB (for example a . (dot)).

```
{"www.example.com":true}
```

Should become this (or any other accepted character):

```
{"wwwexamplecom":true}
```

I've done this several times before with JavaScript. But it's my first time in python and I wonder if there is a function or library for that task? I looked through the JSON chapter of the python documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#) but did not find a solution to this.

Maybe someone knows the answer?

Many thanks in advance,

Daniel

Edit:
I think it's more a duplicate of what @alecxe write in his answer.

Edit 2:
Maybe this threat is also related [How can I edit/rename keys during json.load in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11189108/3194041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397118/mongodb-dot-in-key-name) and the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names), you should only worry about `.` and `$` in the key names. Simply replace them:

```
key = key.replace(".", "").replace("$", "")
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is good, but for me only the second step. I need to go through a whole JSON-String. Is there a "python way" of going through all JSON keys and then apply your method? Or do I have to build a new JSON String?